# How Do I calculate the volume of D?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, vector-spaces

How do I calculate the volume V of D :

D = {$(x,y,z)\in R^3$ : $x^2+y^2<=z^2+9,|z|\le 3$}

I know that i have to use the triple integral:

$\int\int\int_V div(F)dV$

$\int\int\int_Vdxdydz= Vol(V)$

how do I procede from here ? 
what do I need to put here '*'

$\int_{*}\int_{*}\int_{*}***d*d*d* = Vol(D)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}\bracks{x^{2} + y^{2} \leq z^{2} + 9}
\bracks{\verts{z} \leq 3}\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z\ =\
\overbrace{\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}\bracks{r^{2} \leq z^{2} + 9}
\bracks{\verts{z} \leq 3}r\,\dd r\,\dd \theta\,\dd z}
^{\ds{\mbox{Cylindrical Coordinates}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{r^{2} \leq z^{2} + 9}
\bracks{\verts{z} \leq 3}r\,\dd r\,\dd \theta\,\dd z
\\[5mm] = &\
2\pi\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{r \leq z^{2} + 9}
\bracks{\verts{z} \leq 3}\,{1 \over 2}\,\dd r\,\dd z\label{1}\tag{1}
\\[5mm] = &\
2\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{z \leq 3}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{r \leq z^{2} + 9}\,\dd r\,\dd z\label{2}\tag{2}
\\[5mm] & =
2\pi\int_{0}^{3}\pars{z^{2} + 9}\,\dd z = \bbx{\ds{72\pi}}
\end{align}

Comment: why the outer integral is between -inf and +inf ? should't be -3 --- +3 ?

Comment: @NPLS You can see in line $\color{#f00}{1}$ that the integrand is an $even$ function of $z$. So, multiply by $2$ and integrate over $\left(0,\infty\right)$. It yields a prefactor $\color{#f00}{2} \times 2\pi \times 1/2 = \color{#f00}{2\pi}$ in line $\color{#f00}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

You may simply integrate along sections. For any $z_0\in(-3,3)$ the section is a circle with squared radius $z_0^2+9$, hence area $\pi(z_0^2+9)$. By Cavalieri's principle the volume is given by
$$ \int_{-3}^{3}\pi(z^2+9)\,dz = \color{red}{72\,\pi}.$$